# Replacing ng-router with ui-router on the Angular-fullstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, yeoman, angular-ui-router

problem 1:  `url:/home, templateUrl: 'index.html` is rendering twice.

problem 2:  `views: templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.html` is not being rendered at all

**What am I missing? How do I properly integrate ui-router into [yeoman](http://yeoman.io)'s [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo)?**

**app/scripts/app.js:**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
                },
                'navigation@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/navigation.html',
                    controller: 'NavigationCtrl'
                },

                'menu@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/menu.html',
                    controller: 'MenuCtrl'
                },
                'weekly@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/weekly.html',
                    controller: 'WeeklyCtrl'
                },
                'sidepanel@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/side-panel.html',
                    controller: 'SidePanelCtrl'
                },
                'shoppanel@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/shop-panel.html',
                    controller: 'ShopPanelCtrl'
                },
                'footer@home': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/_partials/footer.html',
                    controller: 'FooterCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

[image]

**app/index.html**

```
<div class="container" ui-view></div>
```

**app/views/main.html**

```
    <!-- z-100 fixed-->
<section ui-view="navigation" id="navigation"></section>

<!-- z-5 fixed-->
<section ui-view="weekly" id="weekly" class="panel" ></section>

<!-- z-10 relative top:100%; margin-bottom: 33%;-->
<section ui-view="content" id="content" ></section>




<!-- z-1 fixed height: 33%;-->
<section id="footer" ui-view="footer" ></section>

<!-- z-1 fixed -->
<section id="ui">

    <div ui-view="sidepanel" id="side-panel" class="panel"></div>
    <div ui-view="shoppanel" id="shop-panel" class="panel"></div>

</section>
```

**/lib/routes.js**

```
  app.route('/partials/*')
   .get(index.partials);
  app.route('/*')
   .get( index.index);
```

**lib/controllers/index.js**

```
var path = require('path');

/**
 * Send partial, or 404 if it doesn't exist
 */
exports.partials = function(req, res) {
  var stripped = req.url.split('.')[0];
  var requestedView = path.join('./', stripped);
  res.render(requestedView, function(err, html) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error rendering partial '" + requestedView + "'\n", err);
      res.status(404);
      res.send(404);
    } else {
      res.send(html);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Send our single page app
 */
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I'm kind of confused a little by your code, but try my tweaks. I've been working on a barebones framework that stacks mongo/express/angular/node with jade as a view engine, and based on what I've seen in the lib directory of the project on github, the changes should work.

For problem #1, in your /libs/routes.js, change:

```
app.route('/partials/*').get(index.partials);
app.route('/*').get( index.index);
```

to

```
app.get('/partials/*', index.partials);
app.get('/*', index.index);
```

For problem #2, in your app/scripts/app.js, change:

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.html'
          }
        }
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

to

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',

        views: {
            'navigation': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/navigation.html',
                controller: 'NavigationCtrl'
            },

            'menu': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/menu.html',
                controller: 'MenuCtrl'
            },
            'weekly': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/weekly.html',
                controller: 'WeeklyCtrl'
            },
            'sidepanel': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/side-panel.html',
                controller: 'SidePanelCtrl'
            },
            'shoppanel': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/shop-panel.html',
                controller: 'ShopPanelCtrl'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'views/_partials/footer.html',
                controller: 'FooterCtrl'
            }
        }
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

You will already be requesting index.html (via h t t p : / / <your host>/#/home, index.html is loaded by the web server by default more than likely), so there's no reason to request it again in your app.js file. Also, you have define the /partials/* route in your routes.js file, so that's why /views/partials was changed to /partials. Kind of pointless IMO, your /views/partials/main.html should load just fine because the framework has express static routes setup for /tmp and /app directory.

Try to visit your partials and make sure they are serving up. if you can't type h t t p : / / <your host>/<partial directory>/main.html and get the contents of the file back, ui-router won't be able to pull the contents as well. Make sure to check your DevTools for GET errors.

I apologies a head of time for any typos.

Comment: what if I have many views?  I know it's wonky now but in the end I'll have many absolute paths.  app/scripts/app.js updating code above 10 seconds

Comment: could you shed a bit more light on how i would address absolute paths and requests using ui-router and the mean stack?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'many views'? Additional separate views or nested views inside of an already nested ui-router view? I've been meaning to write a blog post regarding nested views with ui-router, but haven't gotten around to it yet. You can continue to define states. After the home state (and before the semi colon), you could have .state('home', { url: '/about', templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'}). Make sure that about.html exists.

Comment: Since the framework you use checks for whether a file exists or not in the tmp/ and app/ directory (https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/lib/config/express.js Line 26-27). So if you had a file with an server path of 'app/staticfile.js', you can reach that file by typing http://<server>/staticfile.js. And this is all if you are in development mode and not production mode.

To be honest, I am kind of confused by how this framework does things and why it does such things. If you are capable to make your own MEAN stack, it will be a better learning experience for you.

Comment: 'Can you elaborate on many views' https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views..

Comment: I havent been home to test your answer;however, will multiple-named views conflict with your answer above?  in my question i've listed out my new angular ui-router routes.

Comment: Multiple-named views simply won't load because they were not specified in the state I suggested previously. I will change my recommendation accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55242/discussion-between-verron-knowles-and-matthew-harwood).